# How to save data to Parse backend in iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to use Parse to save data for my iPhone app. When I save static things, it works fine. However, when I try to set the value of a variable and then save it, I get an error saying, “Implicit conversion of ‘int’ to ‘id’ is disallowed with ARC.”

How do I fix this so I can save the value of maxScore to my Parse backend?

```
int maxScore = 500;
//Save round data to parse
PFObject *roundScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserCoor"];
roundScore[@"UserLat"] = maxScore;
[roundScore saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, it expects a a pointer to an Objective-C object, and instead of an object, you're passing in a primitive type (int). You may want to use

```
NSNumber *maxScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:500];
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't can't pass a primitive type such as `int` to `roundScore[@"UserLat"] = maxScore`. This keyed subscript notation is just a call to `setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key`, which as you can see takes a object of type `id` as the obj parameter.

You can box your int value into an `NSNumber` (not a primitive type) easily by using the literal `@()`. Like so:

```
roundScore[@"UserLat"] = @(maxScore);
```